# Implemented merge sort for large CSV files in Python3, slow performance

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, csv

so I decided to implement merge sort in Python3 to handle large CSV files (working with 5GB files >.<) and I think I have the logic down correctly, the problem is, that it's quite slow, I'm just wondering if you guys have any suggestions on how to alter my code for a faster performance?
Thanks and please bear with my code, I'm still new to Python ^^

Here's the main piece of the merge sort code, note that this is **after** breaking the file into chunks and sorting each chunk:

```
def merge_sort():
    files_to_merge = os.listdir(temp_folder)
    files_left = len(files_to_merge)
    print("Merging {} files...".format(files_left))
    temp_file_count = files_left + 1

    while files_left != 1:
        first_file = temp_folder + files_to_merge[0]
        print(first_file)
        second_file = temp_folder + files_to_merge[1]
        print(second_file)
        # Process both files.

        with open(first_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file_1:
            with open(second_file, 'r', encoding='utf-8')as file_2:
                # Setup
                temp_file = temp_folder + "tempFile - {:03}.csv".format(temp_file_count)
                file1_line, file2_line = file_1.readline(), file_2.readline()
                compare_values_list = [file1_line.split(','), file2_line.split(',')]
                print("Writing to >> {}...".format(temp_file))
                # Keep going until all values have been read from both files.
                with open(temp_file, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as m_file:
                    while len(compare_values_list) != 0 or (file1_line != '' or file2_line != ''):
                        # Grab the highest value from the list, write to a file, and delete it.
                        compare_values_list.sort(key=sorter)  # sorter = operator.itemgetter(sort_key)
                        line_to_write = ','.join(compare_values_list[0])
                        del compare_values_list[0]

                        m_file.write(line_to_write)

                        # Get the next values from the file and check whether to add to the list.
                        file1_line, file2_line = file_1.readline(), file_2.readline()
                        if file1_line != '' and file2_line != '':
                            compare_values_list.append(file1_line.split(','))
                            compare_values_list.append(file2_line.split(','))
                        elif file1_line != '' and file2_line == '':
                            compare_values_list.append(file1_line.split(','))
                        elif file1_line == '' and file2_line != '':
                            compare_values_list.append(file2_line.split(','))
        # Clean up files and update values.
        os.remove(first_file)
        os.remove(second_file)
        temp_file_count += 1
        files_to_merge = os.listdir(temp_folder)
        files_left = len(files_to_merge)
    print("Finish merging files.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 slow parts that jump out.

First is that your script opens the tempfile whenever it writes something.  Move these line outside the nested while loop:

```
with open(temp_file, 'a', encoding='utf-8') as m_file:
    m_file.write(line_to_write)
```

You could might also consider saving the data to a variable in memory, but I'm not sure how good of an idea that is if the file will be large.

Second, is your use of `compare_values_list`.  You are frequently appending and deleting, which is requires a lot of work for reallocating space in memory.  You're also recreating the list from scratch *very* often.  First try avoiding the copy of the list for each loop and sort in place:

```
compare_values_list.sort(key=sorter)
```

should help you avoid that.  If you want to try to make it faster, preallocate the list and manage it's size.  Something like:

```
compare_values_list_capacity = 1000
compare_values_list_size = 0
compare_values_list = [None]*compare_values_list_capacity
```

though I am hazy on the details of mixing these 2 solutions - I'm not sure this will work with the sorting in place, so it's worth trying both and seeing which works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I re-edited the code to add some of your suggestions, it has improved the speed a bit, but it's still having a hard time with a 500MB file (So I'm a little unsure about throwing a 5GB one at it yet) I'll have to edit a little more for your third suggestion, but I think I'll hold off on that to see what others suggest

Comment: Another idea might be to remove the sorting all together.  Sorting is O(n*log(N)), and you just need the minimum.  Finding the min is O(n).